# How to use schema.dump feature with a plucked data_key?

Tags: marshmallow

I am using Flask-Marshmallow and Flask-SQLAlchemy to dump data to an API.

I have an option in the API to dump specific fields in the response:

```py
schema = UserSchema()
schema.dump(data, only=fields)
```

I get an error if one of the field names is derived if it is plucked using the data_key feature:

`ValueError: Invalid fields for <UserSchema()>: {'account_name'}.`

**CLARIFICATION**: To correctly filter this field the client has to pass accountname to return account_name. This is undesirable since the client is not exposed to the internal implementation.

Example Code:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)

    account = db.relationship('Account', backref='user')


class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    accountname = db.Column(db.String)


class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        include_fk = True
        sqla_session = db.session

    account = ma.Pluck('AccountSchema', 'accountname', data_key='account_name')


class AccountSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        include_fk = True
        sqla_session = db.session
```

Is there a trick to get Marshmallow to dump based on the data_key?

**UPDATE:** I am currently solving this with a brute force method by decorating the controller functions with a mapper. But, it would be nice if Marshmallow could handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is that you pass user data (name of keys from client side) into method from object world (dump) that is not meant to.

I don't think it would work even if there was no `Pluck` field involved, would it?

You need a layer translating user field selection into object world (field names).

This is the mapping you're using. Maybe you could generate the mapping automatically by introspecting the schemas. This can be done in a base schema class.

Comment: The schema is a sub-class of ma.SQLAlchemySchema. This introspects into the DB and returns all of the fields in the model. The API is calling the schema.dump method after fetching the data. The client sees account_name in the response, but a client is not able to filter down to that field using account_name. They have to pass accountname as the filter to return account_name. This is undesired since the internal object model is not exposed in the API. Does that make sense?

Comment: Absolutely. You need a layer to translate client-side field names into object/DB field names. The lib can't do this for you. You can define a mapping manually. Or maybe you could introspect the schema to build the mapping from field names and data_key attributes.